# Web application landline caller id using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-applications, caller-id

I am currently working on an application for which it would be very useful to automatically identify the phone number of a landline call made to a specific phone.

After some research, I have found a few packages (e.g npm caller-id-node) which seem to work for desktop applications using the modem. My application, however, is a web application and I am not sure whether those same packages can or cannot be used via the browser and how. I realize this is a very vague question, but I could not find anything more detailed online.

I guess another option would be to make a small desktop application which will take care of the caller id and then somehow connect it to the web application via localhost. Would this be the recommended way? Is there a better option maybe? It would be great if I could spare the user from typing in the phone number every time. Any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just use [ElectronJs](https://www.electronjs.org/).

Actually, this is on my Todo list right now.
I think the best solution would be using [ElectronJs](https://www.electronjs.org/)
which gives you more flexibility than other options(like writing a middleware to receive data) since you can use node packages alongside the same UI you're using right now.

plus since CallerId use your hardware ports, there is no way you could implement this directly on browser easily (and a few browsers would support that)